# Get value of a input in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I'm not familiar with wicket.

I want to get value of input in html page and convert it to a string and work on it in java mode, but I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's an incredibly broad question. Maybe you should work through some wicket tutorials first before asking here. The official user guide is a good place to start: https://wicket.apache.org/learn/#guide

Comment: I watch some tutorials but I did not get anywhere. I have <input wicket:id="carrierName"> and I want just to save it's value in "private String carrierName" in java code. I did't find enything in my search.

Comment: If you have a problem with a specific example, you should use that example to explain your problem. Right now, you are asking for a guide and this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
    PasswordTextField ptf = new PasswordTextField("password", Model.of(""));

    Form form = new Form("exampleForm"){
                @Override
                public void onSubmit() {
                   System.out.print(ptf.getModelObject());
                }
    }
    form.add(ptf);
```

So When u submit the form - you get get submitted value from Password Text Field by calling getModelObject() method on textField object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wicket Examples Echo application as inspiration:

Demo: http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/echo

Code: https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/e5ce1df6aa7f55ab3e1a0dac8b8d09250b510c1f/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/echo